# Module exports for Express Router / Functions

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, express-router

Hi I am trying to export both a function (so that other routes may use this function to verify certs and also a the express router so that I can add it to my main class to mount the route on. This is because I believe the function and the route both serve the same sort of "functionality" and I want to encapsulate it in one file, so I want to export both the function and the router to use! Here is the following code of which I get an error... Note I WANT to do verifytoken.router to refer to the router and then verifytoken.verify to refer to the function in other files

/routes/verifytoken.js file

```
const router = require('express').Router();
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');

function verify (req, res, next) {
    const token = req.header("auth-token");
    if (!token) return res.status(401).send("Access Denied");

    try {
        const verified = jwt.verify(token, process.env.TOKEN_SECRET);
        req.user = verified;
        next();
    } catch (error) {
        res.status(400).send("Invalid Token")
    }
}

router.get("/tester", (req, res) => {
    res.status(200).send("validation please work bro"); 
});

module.exports = {
    verify:verify,
    router:router
}
```

my main index.js file

```
const express = require('express');

//import routes
const verifytoken = require('./routes/verifytoken')

const app = express(); 

//route middlewares
app.use("/api/user". verifytoken.router);

app.listen(3000 , () => console.log('Server Running...'))
```

The stack trace is :

```
app.use("/api/user". verifytoken.router);
                                 ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'router' of undefined
```

Comment: What's the error after the updated filename?

Comment: the same error, it wasn't a filename problem I updated the post it was a typo for the POST not in my program. The same error still exists

Answer (score 3):

1) Another typo:

```js
app.use("/api/user". verifytoken.router);
```

Should be: (note dot . instead of comma ,)

```js
app.use("/api/user", verifytoken.router);
```

2) You're using the wrong filename in the imported module:

```
const verifytoken = require('./routes/verifytoken');
```

Should be:

```js
const verifytoken = require('./routes/verify');
```

The required file is named **verify.js** not **verifytoken.js**

Comment: sorry I misspelt the filename i updated it the filenames are correct. Its still not working

Comment: no its the same error I just had a typo when making this post, try running this locally youll get the same error

Comment: OH MY GOD THIS WAS THE ERROR THANK YOU GUYS SO MUCH!!!!  the DOT

Answer (score 1):

I think there's another typo (dot), try:

```
app.use("/api/user", verifytoken.router);
```

Comment: I'm glad I could help!